# looking for adsr plugin (adsr)

Tags: plugins, vst

i'm looking for a good adsr vst-effect - it should be fast and clean and support automation.
any ideas?

thanks

Comment: SPL transient modifier? or Sonnox? or you don't plan to use it as a transient shaper but as an actual ADSR?

Comment: Which ones have you checked out already?

Answer (score 1):

Fuxi, you can try [ndc Midi ADSR](http://www.niallmoody.com/ndcplugs/midiadsr.htm), found in [FreeMusicSoftware.org](http://freemusicsoftware.org/category/free-vst-effects-2/envelopes), I've just tested it with Reaper 3.74 and it seems to work fine.

Unfortunately its not tempo syncable - the 'segment' value is in seconds.

Check out the other VSTs on the Free Music Software site.